# Intermediate value theorem using

Tags: calculus, continuity

Consider $f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow \left[0,1\right]$, continuous function.
For which values of $a$ there must be exist $c\:\in \left[0,1\right]$ such that $f\left(c\right)\:=\:a\cdot c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-ax$ so $g$ is continuous and assume that

$$g(0)g(1)\le0\iff f(0)(f(1)-a)\le0\iff f(1)-a\le0\iff f(1)\le a$$
so with this assumption (i.e. $f(1)\le a$) and by the intermediate value theorem the desired resuld follows.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(0) = 0$, then $a$ can be any real number. If $f(0) > 0$, then any $a \ge 1$ will do. For the function $g(x) = f(x) - ax$ has $g(0) = f(0) > 0$ and $g(1) = f(1) - a \le 1 - a \le 0$. So by the intermediate value theorem, there must be a $c\in [0,1]$ such that $g(c) = 0$, i.e., $f(c) = ac$. If $a \le 1$ and $f(0) > 0$, then there need not exist a $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c) = ac$. For example, the constant function $f(x) = 1$ has no $c\in [0,1]$ that satisfies $ac = f(c)$.